# how to set the password to SA user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My Windows account has administrator rights on a local SQL Instance. I am able to change the password to `SA` user but when I try to login using `SA` with SQL Server authentication mode it gives me error. I am trying to access a local database.

Can somebody please help me to set the password and login to the local SQL using SQL authentication mode?

Comment: Is your server configured to work in mixed mode?

Comment: "it gives me error" - you know, sometimes those error messages contain *useful information*. If you could tell us *what error* you're getting, we might be able to help.

Comment: @DavidBrabant can you please tell me how can i check for the mixed mode it would be good if we can check it using sql qeury.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the sa password

In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine.

On the Standard bar, click New Query.

Copy and paste the following example into the query window and click Execute. The following example enables the sa login and sets a new password.

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

check this link

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/29/sql-server-change-password-of-sa-login-using-management-studio/